# Is AudioSource.Play() async a function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio-player

### Expectation

1. first, the Brick produces a sound.
2. then, the Brick disappears.

### Code

```
public class Brick : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource _audio;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    public void OnCollisionEnter2D()
    {
        _audio.Play();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

### Result

the Brick produces no sound and the Brick disappears.
I wonder why the Brick produces no sound.

### Guess

[reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.Play.html)
does not say that it is async, however, AudioSource.Play() is async function?

### codicil

of course, the gameObject attaced c#Brick.cs has valid AudioSource.
So when I write code at `Start()` like this , Brick produces a sound properly.

```
public void Start()
{
    _audio.Play();
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer after you accepted. Destroy has second parameter which is the delay, so you can just use _audio.clip.length as the second argument and you don't have to manually poll the _audio.isPlaying every frame.

Comment: @FINDarkside Thank you for teaching me great solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is async. If it wasn't async your whole game would freeze until the sound effect is played. One way to solve your issue is to have one GameObject dedicated to being AudioSource and then using [AudioSource.PlayOneShot](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.PlayOneShot.html) to play all the sound effects.

Another option would be to destroy the Brick once the audio is played. You should probably remove/disable the SpriteRenderers and colliders so the block wouldn't be visible. Destroy has second parameter, which is the delay before the object is destroyed.

Example code for the second option:

```
_audio.Play();
GetComponent<Collider2D>().enabled = false;
GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
Destroy(gameObject, _audio.clip.length);
```